# Neo4j create multiple relationships with ActiveNode and Bootstrap Multiselect in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, neo4j

I am playing around with Neo4j and Rails and I have created an app that creates new nodes and relationships using ActiveNode. This is my current data model:

```
(company1)-[:RESEARCHING]->(market1)
(company2)-[:RESEARCHING]->(market2)
```

I have a company page with a dropdown menu that contains "market1" and "market2". When I create a company, I can select "market1" and a new relationship is created between that company and "market1". If I update the company, I can change the item in the dropdown and it will delete the old relationship and create a new one.

What I would like to do is to hook this dropdown menu to Bootstrap Multiselect so I can select multiple markets from my dropdown to create multiple relationships at once. Something like this:

```
(market2)<-[:RESEARCHING]-(company1)-[:RESEARCHING]->(market1)
```

I have most everything figured out, my Bootstrap menu works except it doesn't update the database. I just don't know where to put this bit of code that adds the relationship upon submit:

```
@company.market.try(:id)
```

(At least I think it does.) Any ideas on how to do this? Thanks in advance!

Here is my code:

```
<!-- Current working form. -->
<div class="field">
  <%= f.label :market %><br>
  <%= f.select "market", 
  options_from_collection_for_select(Market.all, "id", "name", @company.market.try(:id)) %> 
</div>

<div class="actions">
  <%= f.submit %>
</div>

<!-- The form I would like to create. -->
<form id="form1">
  <div style="padding:20px">
    <select id="market" multiple="multiple">
      <% @markets.each do |market| %>
        <option name="<%= market.name %>" value="<%= market.name %>"><%= market.name %></option>
      <% end %>
    </select><br><br>

  <div class="actions" id="submit" value="Submit">
    <%= f.submit %>
  </div>

  <script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
      $('#market').multiselect({
       includeSelectAllOption: true
      });
      $('#submit').click(function() {
      })
    });
  </script>
 </div>
</form>
```

Comment: What do your `params` look like in your controller when you submit the form?  If it works right you should get an Array of ids for `params[:market]` (might want to rename that to `markets`) and then you should be able to assign that to your association like `@company.markets = params[:markets]` (it should be a `has_many` association as well)

Answer (score 0):

Please bear with me, I haven't worked with `options_from_collection_for_select` before. It looks like it just needs to know whether the form already has this selected, so I think it might be best to figure that out first, then check each market against that list. The [API docs](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper/options_from_collection_for_select) look like we can give that a proc, so maybe something like this?

```
<% @selected_markets = @company.markets(:m).pluck('m.uuid') %>
<%= f.select "market", 
  options_from_collection_for_select(Market.all, "id", "name", proc { |market| @selected_markets.include?(market.uuid) }) %>
```

This assumes that you have a `markets` association on the `Company` model.

Comment: I haven't worked with `options_from_collection_for_select` much before either but that looks like a good way of going about it. Some other things came up but I'll do some playing around when I have time and will let you know when I figure it out!